# Don't send message if length < 2

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to add php to my contact us page to make sure the message is at least a few characters long for it to be sent. I have tried if (strlen()> 2) but it is just letting messages go through anyway.`enter code here`

```
<div id="phillya11">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#FFF5ee">
        Contact us
    </a>
</div> 

<div id="soon4">
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
        <p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
        <p>Message</p>
        <textarea style="width:475px; height:175px;margin-left:7%" name="message"></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
    </form>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
    if (strlen($message)> 2)
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "myemail";
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#phillya11").click(function () 
{
    $("#soon4").show();
    $("#soon").hide();
    $("#soon1").hide();
    $("#soon2").hide();
    $("#soon3").hide();    
    $('#close4').click(function () 
    {
        $("#soon4").hide();
    });
```

Comment: Missing braces, double-check your syntax.

Comment: You might want to check out the PHP documentation regarding control structures. (For example [the documentation page regarding the 'if' statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php).) Search for "statement group".

Comment: @Tomas Creemers i see now anytime i use if's they have to be in <?php   ?>

Comment: @phil no ... `ALL` php code must be between <?php and ?>. Not just if's.

Comment: @Dave sorry i mean if i was going to do a if, it has to be between the tags and then if i want to do another that one would have to be between it's own tags to? Am i right?

Comment: @PhilFamme no you dont need to keep closing and opening tags.. see my answer i've given you the information.

Comment: @Dave  overload for me lol! was thinking php was same as js with if's, then for some reason was thinking everything in php had to be in it's own tags. I see now same as js. Thanks your answer works perfect, I appreciate it!

Comment: @PhilFamme JS is the same.. you don't need to use <script></script for every if statement either. Infact it applies to all languages. You just do : `<?php all php code here; ?>` pretty simple :P

Comment: @Dave i see. I learned it in a editor, and this is my first time using it. but i should know better lol!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$message` is not set yet so the if statement will fail. Change it to the post message. You also need to check the message is set before you check its string length.

Note also the use of `{ }` with the `if` statement when the statement is true the content between the curly braces executes.

```
<?php
  //$message  is not set here until inside the if statment
  //there for we should check $_POST['message']
  //if $_POST['message'] has the criteria you seek
  //THEN $message will be set as shown at line 5 which i marked for you to see

  if (isset($_POST['message']) && strlen($_POST['message'])> 2) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message']; //line 5 $message now set
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "myemail";
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo "Thank You!";

 } else {
    echo 'Your message must be longer than 2 characters!';
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This method uses the `if message is less than 2 characters`, then do not process the execution for the `mail()` function. If the message is more than that, then it will proceed in executing the `mail()` function.

```
<?php 

if (strlen($_POST['message']) < 2) {
die("Sorry, try again.");
}

else {

$name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "myemail";
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo "Thank You!";

}

?>
```

Comment: Why does he have to check it's less than 2? You can do > 2 and use an else statement for when it is not.

Comment: @Fred i tried it and no messages could get through, if they where > then 2 or not.

Comment: @PhilFamme No problem. Well you have many to choose from. I'm just offering you another option, which was your original intent.

Comment: @Dave Because that was the OP's original intent.

Comment: @Dave Sure, that too. I agree with you 100% on that. *"Don't send message if length < 2"* as per title.

Comment: Just change the word `should` to something that won't sound like its better option :P It might make new people think its the only correct way.

Comment: @Dave You're right Dave, I agree with you again, thanks for that. - Done.

Comment: @Dave The OP found a solution and that's the important thing. Glad he picked yours, way to go ;-)

Comment: @Dave To tell you the truth Dave, I actually like your method better, cheers. (*Peace*)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    if (strlen($message)> 2) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
        $recipient = "myemail";
        $subject = "Contact Form";
        $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
        mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
        echo "Thank You!";
    }    


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (strlen($_POST['$message'])> 2) {
   ' do something;
}
```